# Does Google recommend to use v7 appcompat support Toolbar or androidx?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, androidx, appcompat-v7-toolbar

I am learning how to implement the App/Action bar in Android and I found the [Add the app bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar) Google's guide, which recommends using the v7 appcompat support libraries. The guide is updated to December 2019.

At the same time, I believe Google recommends androidx, which, as far as I understand, is not compatible with the v7 appcompat support libraries.

What is the actual Google standard and what are the pros and cons of the two alternatives?

Comment: clicking on `v7 appcompat` in the lesson you've provided will give you all the info you need (not the downvoter)

Comment: Thank you a_local_nobody! Do you mean clicking on the tag to search other answers?

Comment: no, i mean in the lesson you've provided, [this is what i'm referring to](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features#v7-appcompat)

Comment: I understand, you mean that one should use androidx. But my point is that Google has an updated guide that explicitly directs to use v7 appcompat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I found the Add the app bar Google's guide, which recommends using the v7 appcompat support libraries. The guide is updated to December 2019.

I filed [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162459305) to try to get them to update this guide. Given my track record of getting documentation bugs fixed, this may take quite some time.

> I believe Google recommends androidx

Correct.

> which... is not compatible with the v7 appcompat support libraries.

The story there is a bit complicated, but, it's 2020, so just use the Jetpack/AndroidX version of `Toolbar`. Probably some of that guide will still be accurate, other than the package names for the classes.

> What is the actual Google standard

Use `androidx` classes instead of `android.support` alternatives for all new development.

> what are the pros and cons of the two alternatives?

The Android Support Library (`android.support`) is no longer being maintained. While the code still runs, you will find increasing compatibility challenges both with AndroidX libraries and possibly with new Android features.

Comment: Then I'd recommend to rate that page as unusable (e.g. give 1 star): https://developer.android.com/training/appbar